# How to prevent keys/keyrings from snagging on clothes

Tags: clothing, storage, metals, repair, keys

How do I keep [split rings used for keeping keys together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain#Keyring) from snagging on clothes, thereby damaging them?

[image: This keyring eats clothes alive]

The keyring in the photo above is an extreme example of their ability to destroy clothes: The smaller ring has bent ever so slightly, causing the one end to easily insert itself into all sorts of fibrous materials and tear them apart with glee.

### Potential solutions

#### Avoidance

Of course, the best way to solve a problem is to avoid it, but there are some cases where this is not feasible: For example, although you could keep their keys in a bag instead of in their pocket, when you take them out to use them and happen to be wearing knit gloves because it's ridiculously cold (so cold that you would never want to take off your gloves just to use your keys), you can easily snag your gloves on the keys and then ruin them.

#### "Snag-proofing"

Now, I could theoretically just replace this ring with a thicker one, but thicker ones can do it as well (albeit not as frequently). In some cases, I've also simply put some electrical tape over the ring so that it no longer has any sharp edges, but then I can no longer quickly take the rings apart (I would have to cut off the tape and then re-apply it), which destroys one of the main advantages of such a design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a thicker, better quality ring to replace the smaller ring. The wire type key ring holder is meant for quick attachment of keys to a tag, not long term use in a pocket. You can find an assorted set of sizes in a package at almost any hardware store.

Comment: I found a different (much thicker) ring and will try it out; Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to look like an ad but it isn't I'm just going to let you know about a product that I bought recently and it helped me with my key problems and yours was one of them, it's called *keysmart* It basically helps you organize your keys. So far I'm loving it, it's sturdy and good quality material(hopefully it lasts long) as of now I have no complaints about it.

[image: Comparison]

So no more keyrings poking through my slacks, and I gotta admit it makes key organization much more easier, I bought it for around 20 USD which at first seemed a bit over the top for a key organizer, but I can tell you that the investment is paying off.

Comment: Looks interesting and I might buy it even if I didn't have the described problem... However, is it perhaps possible to have a key facing "outward" as well, or do the keys somehow "lock" into an inward position?-- My door has an old [lever lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever_tumbler_lock) (I think that's the term) with one of [those really big, long keys, like those you always see in video games](http://blogs.psychcentral.com/therapist-within/files/2011/01/rusty-keys-G-Gawne-Kelnar.jpg).

Comment: I haven't tried putting them facing outward, but I think you can, I'll give it a try, and they don't lock they're just tightened inside the *device* which makes it seem they lock, as for the old school key, that would be interesting to find out.

Comment: Basically, I would put my little keys in them as shown in the picture and then let the big key stick out in the other direction... but I'm not sure that would work, since I don't know what the mechanism is like...

Answer (score 1):

Key "rings" exist that don't have pointy ends.  I've seen some where the 2 ends screw together securely; I think this picture shows one that's just spring-loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keychain with a snap hook to put it on your belt loops, and let the keys hang outside or put them half in your pockets.

[image: key chain on belt loops]
[image: key chain]

Although this solution will not keep the keys together all the time, it will let the keys hang, and therefore not be in the bottom of your pockets where they harm most (according to my experience).